# Push Sharp to send push Notification to IOS App

Tags: ios, asp.net, vb.net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am making a web service for sending push notification to IOS App . I am trying to use Puch Sharp . On web i get the example for Push Sharp 1.1 example but now it is 2.2.

This is the code for version 1.1  . Can some body please tell me what to use in version 2.2 for sending a push notification to IOS App.

```
    '    ''Configure and start Apple APNS
    '    '' IMPORTANT: Make sure you use the right Push certificate.  Apple allows you to generate one for connecting to Sandbox,
    '    ''   and one for connecting to Production.  You must use the right one, to match the provisioning profile you build your
    '    ''   app with!
    Dim appleCert() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "~/DocketTrak_Development.p12"))
    '    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '    ''IMPORTANT: If you are using a Development provisioning Profile, you must use the Sandbox push notification server 
    '    ''  (so you would leave the first arg in the ctor of ApplePushChannelSettings as 'false')
    '    ''  If you are using an AdHoc or AppStore provisioning profile, you must use the Production push notification server
    '    ''  (so you would change the first arg in the ctor of ApplePushChannelSettings to 'true')
    '_push.StartApplePushService(New ApplePushChannelSettings(False, appleCert, "trakDock3%", False))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var push = new PushBroker();

var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
"../../../Resources/PushSharp.Apns.Sandbox.p12"));

push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert,
"CERTIFICATE PASSWORD HERE"));

push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                                       .ForDeviceToken("DEVICE TOKEN HERE")
                                       .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                                       .WithBadge(7)
                                       .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

You can find the latest samples from [here](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Sample/Program.cs)